# Javascript function keeps adding text

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, append

I made a js quiz. Whenever the "next" button is pressed, the text that reads the question number keeps adding text that display the question number instead of replacing it. To help you understand what I mean, [this is the link](http://gnorybeta.net16.net/al1jan16reg.html#/).

This is the code that runs the function for question number:

```
var header = $('<p>Question ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + questions.length + '</p>');
$('#questionnum').append(header);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should actually use `.html()` instead of append. Appending means adding at the end while the `.html` overwrites the `innerHTML` of the element.

```
var header = $('<p>Question ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + questions.length + '</p>');
$('#questionnum').html(header);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use **.text** property instead of **.append** in order to completely change text to new one. .append will keep appending the text.

```
$('#questionnum').text(header);
```

Check out this jquery docs on [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure JavaScript like this as well:

```
document.getElementById("questionnum").innerHTML = header;
```

You won't have such issues doing it this way.

Comment: The problems that may come from that line of code are two:
1) the object with the ID cannot be found
2) header is not a string
These are the two only reasons that may cause an error at that line of code. Make sure the element with the id "questionnum" exists in your code and that the `header` is a string. Hope this helps :)